# Running the model for 8 hours each day for 3 days (AnyLogic)

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

Hope you are all safe,

## 1. My Goal

I am trying to simulate a real situation over 3 days. The system should work 8 hours per day only.

My goal is to run the model 8 hours for 3 days to have enough data to analyze.

## 2. My Problem

I have a schedule for agents' appointments as shown in photo 1. I put the simulation to run from 18.3.2020 at 7:00 am to 20.3.2020 at 3:00. Now the simulation is running 56 hours consecutively and the appointments are not repeated each 8 hours

What I need: Run the model for 8 hours, and when it reruns again (because it is 3 days) the model should reconsider the same appointments in the schedule.

I tried to find a way to input a code that tells Anylogic to run 8 hours every day but I didn't find anything. And I don't want to add more appointment for 24 hours of working, I want it to repeat the schedule for 3 days. AND, there are the boolean start and boolean pause functions, but I don`t know where should I put them.

Does anyone have an idea that can help me?

[image: setup example image]

Thank you.

Comment: this should work. How are you using this schedule?

Comment: I put the appointments of the 8 hours only as shown on photo 1. and assign it to a source and I put the model to run for 1440 min which is 24 hours (8 * 3 ). and still, it doesn`t recognize the schedule after the 8 hours. Moreover, I don`t know how to run the model exactly 8 hours per day. thank you for replying.

Comment: There is a choice to choose "Repeat every" ... days. If I want to use it I need to run the model for 8 hours and then stop it for 16 hours. and redo that for 3 days. I don`t know how to da that

Comment: I said 56 hours to describe the problem only. What I want: Run the model 8 hours per day for 3 days. so the appointments in the schedule are repeated

Comment: then you need to run it for 56 hours and then it will work... you did the schedule correctly i think

Comment: If I run it 56 hours that means 56 hours of working, the other agents such as random walkins will come for 56 hours not 8 hours only

Comment: Then you need to make sure xour random walkins also just arrive in those 8hr windows. AnyLogic will always execute all 24 hrs of a day. If you want to have activity only during 8hr windows, you must set this up manually

Answer (score 0):

Just as Benjamin mentioned, you need to control the arrival of customers within the 8 hour schedule window. One way you can do this my turning off the arrival of the source by changing the arrival rate to zero. This can be done in the Action block of the schedule.

```java
traceln( timeToDate( time() ) + " Schedule Change value=" + value);

// Setting the arrival rate of the Source to zero
if( value == 0 ){
  source.set_rate(0);
}   
// Resetting the arrival back to the original value
// Ensure that the rate units are correct 
else 
  source.set_rate(1, RateUnits.PER_HOUR);
```

[image: result of the code above]

Comment: This is a slightly convoluted solution. He can just use a schedule for his walk-ins Source instead of leaving that with a fixed rate (assuming that's how it's setup) and having a separate schedule to dynamically change its rate.